# How do I access props from child ccomponent?

Tags: reactjs, sip, voip, react-props, react-context

SipProvider is from an npm package react-sip which has context (sip, call, startCall etc) that the child component has access to.
How do I access the context from the child component. (Dailer)

```
import React from 'react'
import { SipProvider } from '@evercall/react-sip'
import Dialer from '../components/Dialer'

const SipReact = () => {
    return (
        <SipProvider
        host="197.159.142.228"
        port={5060}
        pathname="/ws" // Path in socket URI (e.g. wss://sip.example.com:7443/ws); "" by default
        user="27329"
        password={'bB3JwU7i'} // usually required (e.g. from ENV or props)
        autoRegister={true} // true by default, see jssip.UA option register
        autoAnswer={false} // automatically answer incoming calls; false by default
        iceRestart={false} // force ICE session to restart on every WebRTC call; false by default
        sessionTimersExpires={120} // value for Session-Expires header; 120 by default
        debug={false} // whether to output events to console; false by default
        inboundAudioDeviceId={"default"} // default, or a deviceId obtained from navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        outboundAudioDeviceId={"default"} // default, or a deviceId obtained from navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        
      >
        <Dialer  />
      </SipProvider>
  )
}

export default SipReact
```

According to the npm docs, child components(Dialer) has access to this context

```
{
  sip: sipType,
  call: callType,

  registerSip: PropTypes.func,
  unregisterSip: PropTypes.func,

  answerCall: PropTypes.func,
  startCall: PropTypes.func,
  stopCall: PropTypes.func,
}
```

Dailer has this event handler

```
const handleCall = () => {    
    const {
      startCall,
      sip: { status: sipStatus },
      call: { status: callStatus }
    } = props;

    if ( sipStatus !== sipType.SIP_STATUS_REGISTERED) {
      return;
    }
    if ( callStatus !== callType.CALL_STATUS_IDLE ) {
      return
    }
    startCall(number)
  }
```

How do I access SipProvider context from Dailer ?
I tried using props but returns undefiened

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64342795/problem-accessing-context-inside-a-functional-component-on-react implies it's using an older form of the context API

Answer (score 1):

> the child component(Dialer) should have access to startCall, call, sip

Why do you think so? Unless there is some other relevant code that you have not shown, there is no way for the child component to have access to these props. A component only have access to the props you explicitly pass to them. That means in the Dialer component instantiation you need to pass in the value props like this:

```
<Dialer startCall={startCall}/>
```

In order for Dialer component to have access to startCall in its props.

EDIT:

Since you clarified that you are trying to access these values from a context, then the question is phrased wrongly, you are not accessing props, you are accessing context values, they are different things and therefore require different syntax.

I took a quick look at the library repository, and it seems that it is using the old/legacy React context, which has been deprecated in React 17. Assuming you are using an older React version, you can access the context values like this:

```
import { sipPropType, callPropType } from '@evercall/react-sip';

const SipPhone = (props, context) => {

  const Sip = context;

  const handleCall = () => {
    console.log('handleCall', '\n' , Sip)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleCall}>Call</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

SipPhone.contextTypes = {
  sip: sipPropType,
  call: callPropType,
  
  registerSip: PropTypes.func,
  unregisterSip: PropTypes.func,
  
  answerCall: PropTypes.func,
  startCall: PropTypes.func,
  stopCall: PropTypes.func,
}

export default SipPhone;
```

If you are using React 17 and above then you are out of luck, this library won't work, but you can take a look at other alternatives like https://github.com/OpenTelecom/react-sip-phone. I see that some people have volunteered to update the package, but I wouldn't count on it being done anytime soon.

Comment: Edited to original code to give a better picture. SipProvider comes from an npm package react-sip which is context call, sip, startCall available to the child component; in this case Dialer, from which i'm trying to access the context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly pass props to child component like this

```
   const SipPhone = () => {
     return (
        <SipProvider
        host="197.159.142.228"
        port={5060}
        pathname="/ws" // Path in socket URI (e.g. wss://sip.example.com:7443/ws); "" by default
        user="27329"
        password={'bB3JwU7i'} // usually required (e.g. from ENV or props)
        autoRegister={true} // true by default, see jssip.UA option register
        autoAnswer={false} // automatically answer incoming calls; false by default
        iceRestart={false} // force ICE session to restart on every WebRTC call; false by default
        sessionTimersExpires={120} // value for Session-Expires header; 120 by default
        debug={false} // whether to output events to console; false by default
        inboundAudioDeviceId={"default"} // default, or a deviceId obtained from navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        outboundAudioDeviceId={"default"} // default, or a deviceId obtained from navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        
      >
            <Dialer startCall={startCall} sip={sip} call={call}/>
      </SipPhone>
  )
}
```

Comment: Just modified the original code to shed more light.